# Spotfire: Ordering trellis panels based on row number of linked table visualization

Tags: spotfire

It seems the TIBCO Spotfire community forum is down, so I'm asking here in case someone knows how to finaggle this:

I have created a dash:

[image]

The "Hit list" table is a table visualization, which is essentially a filtered version of a much larger data table called "All data" (the values in the table are limited by the values provided in the Text Areas) and only columns of interest are shown. The "All data" table is linked using a unique key to another data table called "Curve data" where all the coordinates for the curves are stored (bottom right on dashboard).

The curves are limited by marking. However, I would like the trellis panels to be ordered by the row number of the table visualization. I.e. in the screenshot below, the trellis panels would be drawn as A24, O6, then O24 rather than the default alphabetical order.

Is this possible? I know I can change the draw order for the trellis panels of the row numbers of the "Curve data" but can I do that for a table visualization?

**Edit:**

Images of snippets of original data tables as requested in comments:

Curve data:
[image]

Data table:
[image]

The two tables are linked (in Data Table properties) according to the "Unique key" column which is a concatenation of the assay plate and well.

Comment: I suspect I am missing something, could you not simply define the trellis as a concatenation of the well (row number) and the actual curve name? A Trellis definition allows for a custom expression.

Comment: Hi Gaia!
I think the issue lies in the fact that the table on the left stems from data table "Final results" and the the trellised curves are from "Curve data". However, I need the curves (from Curve data) to be drawn in the order of the rows selected in the "Final results" table, not the row number of the "Curve data" table

Comment: Is it not possible to join the curve table and the data table and add the well name corresponding to each key to the curve table?

Comment: The data table visualization ("Hit List" in the pic above) has been sorted by a user. What I need is for the trellis panels (data coming from "Curve data") to be ordered in the same order of the selected rows in the visualization. The well, plate name, and a concatenated "Plate_well" column is in Curve data. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting, neither of these will help as the panels are consistently ordered alphabetically and not according to the row number of the table visualization?

Comment: The panels are ordered alphabetically according to their title. You can change the title using a custom expression. That was my suggestion about concatenating. Can you show a sample of these two tables?

Comment: Hey there! I've edited the original post :)

Answer (score 0):

Both your tables (the data table and the curve table) have a column called 'Well' that contains the values you want to order by (in this example, A24, O6, O24). So my suggestion is to put in the Trellis By expression, instead of [Unique_key], the custom expression:

```
<Concatenate([Well],'-',[Unique_key])>
```

which will then be ordered by [Well].

Comment: Ah! I see where the miscommunication is coming in! Ok, so it's by complete chance that the wells I used in the example are in alphabetical order. I need the trellis panels to appear in the order of the selected rows. Concatenating the well ahead of the unique_key won't do that if (for example) I selected K22 (row 9), A24 (row 12) and I20 (row 17). The panels would be drawn A24, I20 and then K22, right?

Comment: I think that might need some scripting then.